# Synergy connects, but mouse won't switch screens (and no debug output showing issue)

Tags: synergy

Trying to setup Synergy, and can't seem to get it right.  Here's the config:

- Server: WinXP with screen named TV
- Client: Ubuntu 11.04 named LAPTOP

Server configuration:

```
section: screens
    LAPTOP:
        halfDuplexCapsLock = false
        halfDuplexNumLock = false
        halfDuplexScrollLock = false
        xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
        switchCorners = none +top-left +bottom-left 
        switchCornerSize = 0
    TV:
        halfDuplexCapsLock = false
        halfDuplexNumLock = false
        halfDuplexScrollLock = false
        xtestIsXineramaUnaware = false
        switchCorners = none +top-right +bottom-right 
        switchCornerSize = 0
end

section: links
    LAPTOP:
        right = TV
    TV:
        left = LAPTOP
end

section: options
    relativeMouseMoves = false
    screenSaverSync = false
    win32KeepForeground = false
    switchCorners = none 
    switchCornerSize = 0
    keystroke(F12) = lockCursorToScreen(toggle)
end
```

When I connect, the server log shows:

```
2011-07-04T09:57:18 NOTE: client "LAPTOP" has disconnected
    ..\lib\server\CClientProxy1_0.cpp,209

2011-07-04T09:57:21 NOTE: accepted client connection
    ..\lib\server\CClientListener.cpp,130
2011-07-04T09:57:21 NOTE: client "LAPTOP" has connected
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,299

2011-07-04T09:57:38 NOTE: client "LAPTOP" has disconnected
    ..\lib\server\CClientProxy1_0.cpp,209

2011-07-04T10:01:48 NOTE: accepted client connection
    ..\lib\server\CClientListener.cpp,130
2011-07-04T10:01:48 NOTE: client "LAPTOP" has connected
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,299

2011-07-04T10:01:53 INFO: screen "LAPTOP" grabbed clipboard 1 from "TV"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,1239

2011-07-04T10:01:53 INFO: screen "LAPTOP" updated clipboard 1
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,1524

2011-07-04T10:02:02 NOTE: client "LAPTOP" has disconnected
    ..\lib\server\CClientProxy1_0.cpp,209

2011-07-04T10:07:01 NOTE: accepted client connection
    ..\lib\server\CClientListener.cpp,130
2011-07-04T10:07:01 NOTE: client "LAPTOP" has connected
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,299

2011-07-04T10:08:40 INFO: screen "LAPTOP" grabbed clipboard 1 from "LAPTOP"
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,1239

2011-07-04T10:08:40 INFO: screen "LAPTOP" updated clipboard 1
    ..\lib\server\CServer.cpp,1524
```

On the client, I run: **synergyc -d DEBUG -f -n LAPTOP -l --log=/tmp/synergy.debug TV**

```
2011-07-04T10:06:50 INFO: Synergy 1.3.6 Client on Linux 2.6.38-10-generic #44+kamal~mjgbacklight4-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 6 19:40:12 UTC 2011 x86_64
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,765
2011-07-04T10:06:50 DEBUG: XOpenDisplay(":0")
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsScreen.cpp,889
2011-07-04T10:06:50 DEBUG: xscreensaver window: 0x00000000
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsScreenSaver.cpp,342
2011-07-04T10:06:50 DEBUG: screen shape: 0,0 1920x1080 
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsScreen.cpp,131
2011-07-04T10:06:50 DEBUG: window is 0x07e00004
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsScreen.cpp,132
2011-07-04T10:06:50 DEBUG: opened display
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/synergy/CScreen.cpp,41
2011-07-04T10:06:50 NOTE: started client
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,339
2011-07-04T10:06:50 NOTE: connecting to 'TV': 192.168.1.75:24800
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/client/CClient.cpp,115
2011-07-04T10:06:59 DEBUG: open clipboard 0
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsClipboard.cpp,316
2011-07-04T10:06:59 DEBUG: empty clipboard 0
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsClipboard.cpp,269
2011-07-04T10:06:59 DEBUG: grabbed clipboard 0
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsClipboard.cpp,292
2011-07-04T10:06:59 DEBUG: close clipboard 0
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsClipboard.cpp,351
2011-07-04T10:06:59 DEBUG: open clipboard 1
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsClipboard.cpp,316
2011-07-04T10:06:59 DEBUG: empty clipboard 1
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsClipboard.cpp,269
2011-07-04T10:06:59 DEBUG: grabbed clipboard 1
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsClipboard.cpp,292
2011-07-04T10:06:59 DEBUG: close clipboard 1
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/lib/platform/CXWindowsClipboard.cpp,351
2011-07-04T10:06:59 NOTE: connected to server
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.3.6/cmd/synergyc/synergyc.cpp,256
```

However, even though everything seems to be connected, my mouse on my laptop never leaves it's current screen.

I don't see any debug messages that could help.  Anybody see anything I'm doing wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out you can use Scroll Lock to keep the mouse stuck on one screen!  So try pressing ScrollLock to see if that releases the mouse.

Comment: That was almost annoyingly easy.

Answer (score 1):

I was just using Fedora 28 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, The Scroll lock didn't help. But what did help was

- Fedora 28, I reverted to same version 1.8.8 as Ubuntu 18.04
- Disable Wayland on Fedora and Ubuntu both
- Restart (the goodluck kiss)

and voila!

Answer (score 0):

upgraded from 1.4.8 to 1.4.10 and this problem appeared for me

Server: win7-64bit Synergy-v1.4.10
Client: Thinkpad T430s Ubuntu-v12.04-32bit Synergy-v1.4.10

tried with a different machine on the client side and still no go:
Client: Thinkpad T420s Ubuntu-v12.10-32bit Synergy-v1.4.10

also tried using the 1.4.8 client in Ubuntu with the 1.4.10 Server in windows and same problems.

so I finally uninstalled synergy 1.4.10 from the client and the server and re-installed v1.4.8 on both and everything works great. same config used on both versions so not that...

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that I tried playing around with SCRLK buttons on both machines for way too long. I got it to work once and I think I hoit some combination of keys but I could not find them ever again so I couldn'tget it working after reboot or service restart.

Comment: This should not really be a comment, but an edit. Click `edit` under your question and put the contents of your comment into the question, and then delete your comment.